# Return value for php class not returning correctly

Tags: php, javascript

I am attempting to return a value from a php class from within Javascript:

```
<html>
<?php 

function tester()
{
return "testing";
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var val= "<?php tester(); ?>";

document.write(val);

document.write('Finished!');
</script>

</html>
```

Nothing is being returned, rather I simply get a blank screen (apart from the "Finished" message) =(

Comment: you mean `<?php echo tester(); ?>`, you forgot to print out :)

Comment: @Mike You're probably best off removing the quotes from around your PHP code and using `json_encode`. See my answer below. That way you can be sure yuo don't print out non-JS-friendly characters - and everything is escaped correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are just returning the value, to output you have to echo it:

```
<?php echo tester(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the output of `tester()`. Try this instead:

```
var val= <?php echo json_encode(tester()); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo it.

Either use:

```
var val= "<?php echo tester(); ?>"
```

Or if you have short tags enabled:

```
var val= "<?=tester()?>"
```

Comment: @War10ck - really? Why? Perhaps you'd be interested to know short-tags are now automatic on PHP 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php